# Undefined reference on libdc1394

Tags: g++, libdc1394

I'm using libdc1394-2.2 for camera Bumblebee2.
However, when I try to release bandwith with code below:

```
if (dc1394_iso_release_bandwidth(camera, val)==DC1394_SUCCESS)
    printf( "Succesfully released %d bytes of bandwidth\n", val);
```

Throws the next error:

```
undefined reference to `dc1394_iso_release_bandwidth'
```

However, the function 'dc1394_iso_release_bandwidth', is included in 'iso.h' and this header is included in the main program.

Someone knows how solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, that function is indeed listed in the dc1394-2 stream `iso.h` header file and with no complex conditional compilation which may cause it to not appear in your translation unit.

One thing that *may* be an issue is the rather common name `iso.h` - I'd modify your `g++` compilation statement to include a `-H` flag, which should list the headers being loaded up. It's *possible* that the `iso.h` header file you're loading is not actually the `dc1394` one.

A long shot, I know, but worth checking if only to discount the possibility.